# Crash when converting NSMutableDictionary to NSData

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, nsdata

In this line

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

i try to convert parameters (NSMutableDictionary) into NSData because i need it for a HTTPRequest.
It was working fine till now but now it crashes saying

```
Crash: Invalid type in JSON write (NSURL)
```

All parameters i give are NSString but 2 of those are in URL format but still NSString and thats where the error is, if i comment those 2 parameters everything is fine.
Any idea?

this is the code

```
+(NSDictionary*)facebookLogIn:(NSString*)facebookID fbEmail:(NSString*)fbEmail fbFullName:(NSString*)fbFullName profilePhoto:(NSString*)profilePhoto coverPhoto:(NSString*)coverPhoto
{
NSError *error;

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@login",API];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:requestString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"Connection" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Keep-Alive"];
[request setCachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];
[request addValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];

NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[parameters setObject:APIKEY forKey:@"APIKEY"];
[parameters setObject:facebookID forKey:@"fbUserID"];
[parameters setObject:fbEmail forKey:@"email"];
[parameters setObject:fbFullName forKey:@"fullName"];
[parameters setObject:profilePhoto forKey:@"profilePhoto"];
[parameters setObject:coverPhoto forKey:@"coverPhoto"];

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[request setHTTPBody:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLResponse *response;
NSData *POSTReply = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];
NSString *theReply = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[POSTReply bytes] length:[POSTReply length] encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSDictionary *JSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: [theReply dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                     options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error: &error];
```

Comment: Sorry I realise I've answered the question without seeing the last sentence, however I'd like to see that code please.

Comment: One of the parameters is a `NSURL`, check it.